# Why does my React component not update on setState

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mern

I am using a MERN stack and have ran into the following problem: My component won't update when the state of one of its props is changed.

````
    const [imgCollection, setImgCollection] = useState([]);

    //When the component mounts it GET's the imgCollection (an array of objects).
    useEffect(() => 
        axios.get(`/api/images/${props.match.params.imgId}`)
        .then(resp => setImgCollection(resp.data))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    , []);

    return(
        <div>
           //This works and displays the image on setImgCollection(...)
            <img src={imgCollection.length > 0 ? `/api/img/${imgCollection[0].filename}` : null} />
           //This doesn't update when the imgCollection state is updated.
           <ImgCarousel imgCollection={imgCollection} />
        </div>
    )
};```

Whatt am I doing wrong!
````

Comment: the code is fine, if you share ImgCarousel component it could be provide more insights

Answer (score 0):

You should add `imgCollection` as a dependency for your `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(() => 
        axios.get(`/api/images/${props.match.params.imgId}`)
        .then(resp => setImgCollection(resp.data))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
, [imgCollection]);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately no luck...

Comment: @GentleCynic Looking more closely to your code, if ```<img>``` works fine, then your data is probably parsed in correctly. Therefore, I would consider the problem is from your ```<ImgCarousel>``` component. Could you provide more context to that component? Could you console.log your ```imgCollection```?